# Reference on Grassmanian

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, grassmannian

Can anyone suggest a reference on the Grassmanian which describe the Riemannian structure of the Grassmanian $Gr(k, n)$? Specifically, I want to know about the geodesics, convex neigboorhood, geodesic submanifolds and the like. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what type of thing you are looking for but the following book talks about Grassmann algebra. http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Geometry-Logic-Applications/dp/2881246834

Comment: Is there a standard metric on $\text{Gr}(k,n)$, or one that you have in mind? My guess is that the usual way to look at $\text{Gr}(k,n)$ is as a homogeneous space, so information about geodesics and such would be obtained from knowledge of metrics on homogeneous spaces.